# The germ induced by an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, several-complex-variables

Let $P\in\mathbb{C}[z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Let $a\in\mathbb{C}^n$ be such that $P(a)=0.$ Consider the germ of holomorphic functions at the point $a,$ denoted by $\mathcal{O}_a.$ I have the following question:

Is the germ induced by $P$ at $a$ irreducible in $\mathcal{O}_a$?

Remark: If possible please suggest a reference to understand the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, consider $y^2-x^3-x^2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. It is an irreducible polynomial (by Eisenstein's criterion), but not an irreducible element of $\mathcal{O}_{(0,0)}$, since we have $y^2-x^3-x^2 = (y-x \sqrt{1+x})(y+x \sqrt{1+x})$. (Geometrically, the we look at the curve $V(y^2=x^3+x^2)$, and the completion reveals its two tangent directions at the origin.)

Comment: One more thing if you can suggest, please, are there some conditions known which a poly. must satisfy so that the above is true,

Comment: In the second example,in one variable case, zero is not in the zero set of the polynomial. And the square root of 1+x is not then defined.

Comment: It is sufficient that the polynomial defines a smooth variety, I think.

Comment: ok, and what if the origin is a "regular point"? I meant that locally, in a nbhd of origin, it looks like an n-1 dim. complex submanifold of complex Euclidean space.

Comment: Yes it should suffice that $V(P)$ is regular at $a$. (But I am not 100% sure.)

Comment: Yeah, I too think that's true, I'll try to prove the same. Anyway thanks.